# I have broken npm when I run a npm command I get node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, npm

updating nodejs I broken npm with any command I get `node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)`

all solutions on stack over flow doesnt works for me.

I have  nodejs -v
v8.10.0

node -v
v16.15.1

npm -v
5.4.0

Comment: try updating packages and also check version of `glibc`.

Comment: I have glibc version 2.27 my linux mint version only have 2.27. I uninstalled node v18 because nodejs 18 needs glibc 2.28 but I can not use npm yet

Comment: you have to stick with node 16.X.X, so use `nvm` or download it from nodejs.org and move files manually (I think it also comes with `npm`).

Comment: Downgrading from node 18 to node 16 using nvm solved the problem for me